# How to filter an excel column by Month name?

Tags: excel, vba, filter, autofilter

Given this list in excel:

[image]

How can I filter the rows (base on the date of birth column) when a user selects the name of the month? This is what I have done so far but I have no idea how to manipulate the `DOB` column:

```
Private Sub ComboBox2_Change()
    On Error Resume Next
    If Me.ComboBox2.Value = "<<All>>" Or Me.ComboBox2.Value = "" Then
        If ActiveSheet.AutoFilterMode Then ActiveSheet.AutoFilterMode = False
    Else
        Sheet1.Range("D4").AutoFilter field:=4, Criteria1:=Me.ComboBox2.Value
    End If
End Sub
```

I don't have any idea what should I put on Criteria1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Using AutoFilter for Months

- Playing with the macro recorder, I concluded that the combination of `Criteria1` being between `21` and `32` and `Operator` being set to `xlFilterDynamic` will filter by month.
- It is assumed that `ComboBox1` is on a worksheet and the code is in the worksheet's module.

**Filter by Month**

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub ComboBox1_Change()
    
    Me.AutoFilterMode = False
    
    If ComboBox1.Value <> "<<All>>" And ComboBox1.Value <> "" Then
        With Me.Range("A3").CurrentRegion
            .AutoFilter 4, ComboBox1.ListIndex + 20, xlFilterDynamic
        End With
    End If
    
End Sub
```

**Populate Combo Box**

```
Sub populateComboBox()
    Const cList As String = "<<All>>,January,February,March,April,May,June," _
        & "July,August,September,October,November,December"
    Dim cData() As String: cData = Split(cList, ",")
    ComboBox1.List = cData
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you very much sir. This is cleaner and efficient than what I did.

Comment: If you don't mind sir, why there is a **+ 20** on ListIndex? I mean, what role does it play on the combobox?

Comment: ListIndex represents the index of the currently selected item in the combo box. Since you have put `<<All>>` as the first item it has the index `0`, while the months conveniently have the indexes `1` to `12` (`1` for `January`, `2` for `February`...). As I (kind of implicitly) wrote in the answer, `Criteria1` has to be `21` for `January`, `22` for February... hence `20 + 1 = 21` for `January`, `20 + 2 = 22` for `February`...

Comment: Very interesting! Voted it up. Did you find this way documented somewhere? I cannot imagine what logical mecanism to be applied, than a Microsoft convention. But, it should be documented, I think...

Comment: In the meantime I made some research and find a very interesting page ([here](https://www.excelcampus.com/vba/filter-dates/)), deeply treating the issue:

Comment: @FaneDuru: Thanks. If I would had found that link earlier, I surely wouldn't have needed so long. I just used the macro recorder. Most of the time was lost while being smart and thinking that `11` is `xlFilterValues`, what else could it be. But it was `xlFilterDynamic` which I figured out when replacing `xlFilterValues` with `11` (read from the macro recorder) in the code and then finally checking on `Microsoft Docs`. Also the workbook was crashing, freezing...I thought my `Excel` was finally dead, but it wasn't. I never thought that this could happen with just a wrong parameter.

Answer (score 0):

First you sould in your code convert the month selected into a value (2 for february  for example). Then you should probably extract the month from the DOB colmun by using a for loop like this (where selected month is the number of the corresponding month selected in the combobox):

```
   Dim current_month
    For i=4 To 13 
        current_month = Month(Range("D"&i).value)
        If current_month <> selected_month Then 'The month don't correspond to the selected
            Range("D"&i).EntireRow.Hidden = True 'Hide the row
    next i
```

Let my know if it helps.

Comment: At some point, it works but if I select another month the list returns nothing (it hides all list).

Comment: You sould probably unhide all the rows before filtering it.